# Python-Opencv Write x264 video on memory buffer

Tags: python, opencv, video, buffer, x264

I have a problem for writing x264 video(or single frame) on memory buffer. In opencv for images, imencode and imdecode do this task. But i want save x264 video frame for lower memory usage and sending on internet. I am able to with jpeg but jpeg size bigger than x264 video frame and quality much worser. I searched but i can't find how i write video frame on buffer.

Here is the example code to taking frames on webcam

```
        import numpy as np
        import cv2


        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(3,320)
        cap.set(4,240)
        cap.set(5,30)
        # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'x264')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('.....sample.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (320,240))

        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret==True:
                cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                out.write(frame) #I want to write memory not disk
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            else:
                break

        # Release everything if job is finished
        cap.release()
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, because I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to create a video file, containing image frames? Or something else? Either way, I'm not sure x264 plays well with AVI containers, I'd try MKV instead

Comment: Actually I m trying to send camera frame over the net with udp or tcp/ip. I sent jpg images with successfully (one frame send and send next frame). But i want to send x264 compressed mkv or avi video(or one frame sequentially) file because x264 compress much efficient than jpg.(also better quality i think) I am able to write on disk but i want to write on memory(like numpy array..) x264 video frames because i must to serialize(with pickle or json) the video frames and send over socket. I searched on the net but i cant found how can i do? I think this explanation much clear. This is my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, since the python version of OpenCV merely uses numpy for matrices, which can be pickled, serialised etc. For video streams, OpenCV (both C++ and Python) uses FFMPEG (libav), whose objects you cannot work with in the same way. Are you going to be modifying the content before streaming it? I.e. do you actually _need_ OpenCV, or would it be possible to use another library for streaming the content directly?

Comment: I probably use another library. But i must stream x264 encoded frames due to internet upload bandwith(less memory usage on x264).

Comment: I think you are shooting birds with a cannon right now :) Check out FFMPEG, this might be exactly the tool you are looking for. E.g. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites. Since this solution is far from what you asked, I will not post it as an answer, but FFMPEG is _the_ go-to solution for most video related, and also used internally in OpenCV, VLC, etc. It is easy to use, commandline and can stream your content (e.g. webcam) directly to twitch or something else. Now I dont know exactly what you will be doing, but I would be surprised if it cannot do so.

Comment: Thanks Allan i will look into this site.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do with **cv2.VideoWriter** because you can't reach the encoded video frames before **out.release()**.

The way I have found for my project is implementing [cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp) from *D:\your_directory\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src* and send your captured frames in that library. You will send encoded frames via UDP or TCP/IP and decode where they reach with the same library. Also remember, you need to compile right [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) version to use it.

Comment: How can i send this frames the library and how can i reach for socket sending?

Comment: You can find the a [sample project](https://github.com/dimitrs/video_coding/blob/master/test.cpp) that uses **cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp** for video streaming with opencv and x264 video codec.