# Python: encode video to file/buffer (NOT filename)

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming, codec

I have a stream of images, I want to write them to a file-like object (interface with `.read()` and `.write()`). I want codec-compression of image frames. The context is: I want to be able to use my own transport and increase the performance of sending video streams between containerized machine learning processes. Might be gRPC, might be websockets, either way, I want access to the bytes generated by the codec after feeding it frames, and not have to worry about piping to an external gStreamer/ffmpeg process, because that's extra overhead.

This *ought* to work:

```
import cv2
from io import BytesIO

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'h264')
buf = BytesIO()
out = cv2.VideoWriter(buf, fourcc, 30, (h, w))
```

Or this

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
f = s.makefile()
out = cv2.VideoWriter(f, fourcc, 30, (h, w))
```

but gives a cryptic `TypeError: must be real number, not tuple` because [it's trying to be "clever" with inferring args based on their type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370802/cv2-videowriter-asks-for-a-tuple-as-size-argument-then-rejects-it).

No problem with mkfifo:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/tmp/myfifo', fourcc, 30, (h, w)) # works!
```

So clearly openCV can write to an abstract file. I'd *rather* not use gStreamer and I *could* use a fifo, but what I actually want is either a socket or a byte stream I can send into my own transport. I'm not locked into openCV, either.

Comment: You can PIPE the frames to FFmpeg. Check the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036822/opencv-videowriter-produces-cant-find-starting-number-error) for example.

Comment: @Rotem That's a partial solution I guess, but that's probably on par with gstreamer (maybe a tad less complex). Cool that it's a novel way of doing that, I didn't know you could do pipe with ffmpeg-python.

Comment: You can't solve it using OpenCV. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471054/python-opencv-write-x264-video-on-memory-buffer) for example. I don't think the FFmpeg solution is complicated. You can use `ffmpeg-python` Python binding, or use `ffmpeg` executable using `subprocess` module.

Comment: Yeah, I dug into openCV source and it looks like it isn't gonna happen there, which is a shame. I'll try profiling the piping to ffmpeg approaches, but I have found PyAV, which actually does let me write to a `BytesIO`. No sockets though, I guess it needs to be seekable.